# How can you make an HTTP request to fetch the status.cgi json data from a Ubiquity AirMax or AirFibre radio with javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, http-headers

My goal is to fetch the status data from a UBNT radio (https://www.ubnt.com/) using an HTTP request. The web interface url is formatted as http://192.168.0.120/status.cgi. Making the request requires a authentication cookie. Using the cookie copied from the existing web interface I am able to successfully retrieve the data.

This is my current code using the Meteor framework.

```
radioHost = "http://192.168.0.120";
HTTP.call("POST", radioHost + "/login.cgi",
    {
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data"
        },
        data: {
            username: "ubnt",
            password: "ubnt"
        }
    }, (err, res) = > {
    if(err) return console.log(err);
    var cookie = res.headers["set-cookie"][0];

    HTTP.call("GET", radioHost + "/status.cgi", {
        headers: {
            cookie
        }
    }, (err, res) = > {
        if(err) return console.log("Error");
            console.log(res);
    })
})
```

The above code achieves both request successfully. However the server is responding to the first with a faulty token ("set-cookie" string). Using the cookie from the existing web framework the response is correct.

Here is a library written in Python that I believe does a similar thing. https://github.com/zmousm/ubnt-nagios-plugins

I believe my problem lies within the HTTP request and the web api not cooperating with the username and password.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: what does `192.168.0.120` a local server only you have access to have to do with `ubnt.com` ... and what is the value of `radioHost` .. you mention three potentially different  servers with no apparent link between them! `faulty token` - in what way is it faulty? is it even present?

Comment: 192.168.0.120 is irrelevant other than it is on my local network. Ubnt is the provider of the hardware for the radio I am using. The token (cookie variable) is a 32 digit string provided by the radio formatted like "AIROS_DC9FDB7841FC=8f828448791237ce68cd4b5230e9354c". It is present, but does not match the same token from the web framework.

Comment: you'd get a different token every time you log in wouldn't you?

Comment: Yes. However, the tokens being provided do not work to access the data.

Comment: perhaps you're sending the cookie incorrectly?

Comment: I am able to get the data with a certified token from the existing web framework, so we can narrow that out.

Comment: fair enough - just checking

Comment: I appreciate it. Have you taken a look at the link to the Python library I posted?

Comment: I don't know python well enough to help

Comment: I would issue a GET request first on `login.cgi`, take any cookies if provided and then post to `login.cgi` in this case

Comment: Thank you so much! It worked. If you don't mind posting an answer so I can reward you the bounty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A direct `POST` request to a url is not a recommended way. When you open a browser you just don't directly login. You fetch the page and then submit/login

Not simulating this behavior may impact certain sites depending on how the server works.

So if always want to look at the simulating like a real user/browser would do, make a `GET` request first and then the `POST`.

Also capture any cookies from the first `GET` request and then pass the same on to the next one